# What does this code do?

Tags: perl, grep

This does what I would like it to

```
if (grep {/$dn/} @ad_sys) {
    $is_system = 1;
}
```

but this always returns `1`.

```
if (grep $_ == $dn, @ad_sys) {
    $is_system = 1;
}
```

What does the second piece do?

Comment: It was perhaps helpful if you gave the values of $dn and @ad_sys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`==` is used for numeric comparison, if you need string comparison use `eq`.

Comment: To expand a bit for context: In Perl any string can be implicitly converted to a number. If the string starts with a number that number is the result, otherwise the result is 0. So a comparison like `'foo' == 'bar'` is the same as `0 == 0` which is true. If you `use warings;` you will get warnings like `Argument "bar" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)` to let you know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It filters those elements from the list @ad_sys that are **numerically** equal to $dn.
Then, if the result is not empty, the condition is true and the if-block is entered.

Answer (score 3):

There are two differences between the two pieces of code.

Firstly, as others have pointed out already, there is the issue of the numeric comparison operator.

But secondly, /$dn/ checks to see if $_ contains the data in $dn. $_ eq $dn checks if $_ is exactly equal to $dn.

This difference could cause a problem, for example, if your data consisted of lines read from a file that hadn't been chomped to remove the newline.